# Cannot use $this -> db in Oracle with CodeIgniter

Tags: php, oracle, codeigniter, class, record

I'm using CodeIgniter with Oracle. But this code segment doesn't work because it produces something that won't work in Oracle SQL.

Here's the code of CodeIgniter:

```
$this -> db -> select('id, username, password');
$this -> db -> from('users');
$this -> db -> where('username', $username);
$this -> db -> where('password', $password);
//$this -> db -> limit(1);
```

Here's the produced code segment for SQL:

```
SELECT "id", "username", "password" FROM "users" WHERE "username" = 'jonaii' AND "password" = 'porter'
```

So probably it will result in an error since the `""` doesn't work.

Any suggestion or other command that will work for Oracle?

Comment: If your column and table names are defined as being lowercase this will work just fine. You might need to upper-case the column names given in your calls to `select`, `from`, and `where` - but this depends entirely on how your tables and columns are actually named. When the table was created was it done as `CREATE TABLE "users" ("id" NUMBER, "username" VARCHAR2(100), "password" VARCHAR2(100)`?

Comment: I've tried creating the table with a quotation but it doesn't work. It says invalid identifier. I've also tried upper casing the select, from , and where but it still doesn't work.

Comment: And what happens when you try to execute the query specified in your question? You say "...probably it will result in an error...". Have you executed it?

Comment: Yeah. I've tried executing it in sql workshop but it also doesn't work. But without the quotation it works

Comment: Try changing the column and table names to upper case in your calls to `select`, `from`, and `where` - e.g. `$this->db->select('ID, USERNAME, PASSWORD'); $this->db->from('USERS');`, etc.

Comment: How do you know it will error? I work on Oracle database with codeigniter. And I don't Think your query will not work.Do you get any error from codeigniter? I am sure that your table is UPPERCASE at your database. Try using `USERS`

Comment: So the error is now in the database. I've tried configuring somethings and it works. And I figured that the error was in the database connection.

Here's the code of the database.

`$tnsname = '(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
        (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED) (SERVICE_NAME = XE)))';

$db['default']['hostname'] = $tnsname;
$db['default']['username'] = 'dbms_project';
$db['default']['password'] = 'oracle';
$db['default']['database'] = '';`